# How I can use TFS Source control for my multi solution brown field project

Tags: version-control

I want to use TFS source control for my brown project. My project has many solutions. One solution depends on another solution.  I have module like following.

**BusinessERP.Sales.sln**

```
BusinessERP.Sales.UI
BusinessERP.Sales.BL
BusinessERP.Sales.DAL
BusinessERP.Sales.DTO
```

**BusinessERP.Purchase.Sln**

```
BusinessERP.Purchase.UI
BusinessERP.Purchase.BL
BusinessERP.Purchase.DAL
BusinessERP.Purchase.DTO
```

…. And so on

**BusinessERP.Integration.Sln**

```
BusinessERP. Integration.UI
BusinessERP. Integration.BL
BusinessERP. Integration.DAL
BusinessERP. Integration.DTO
```

Here one module depends on another and integration depends on all individual modules.

My question is how I can use TFS source control

Shall I create single TeamProject and then paste all my solution there. 
If I did that, then by default TFS ignore dll files. So when I want to check out then I get a solution without dll. Then my solution doesn’t run. What is the standard way to keep my solution so that I cannot copy dll or what things I have to do?

Another question is, shall I create Area in TFS under Same Team project? Then under each Area I will put each of my solutions?

Need help how I can start with TFS source control with my multi solution existing project so that I can get all benefit of TFS.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a single **team project** for every ***product/project*** that you have. If the solutions release together, they are part of the same TP.

Have all of the solutions stored together in the source control. This means that if your product is called *BusinessERP*, for example, then your sources will be stored in the following tree-like configuration:
`$/`
`- BusinessERP`
`-- BusinessERP.Sales`
`--- BusinessERP.Sales.UI`
`--- BusinessERP.Sales.BL`
`--- BusinessERP.Sales.DAL`
`--- BusinessERP.Sales.DTO`
`-- BusinessERP.Purchase`

And so on.

If you intend to use a release/versioning plan (and you really should for any serious work), then this is the structure that you will put in the versioning structure. For more on version management in TFS, you may want to refer to the [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

**One important thing to note:** If you are managing your sources in different solutions, make sure to manage the inter-dependency between those solutions properly. Make sure that you don't depend on sources from external solutions, but rather on their **outputs**, and manage those the same way you would with 3rd party dependencies. This will save you a lot of problems when you try to set up a new development environment, as well as avoid situations where the dependent solution breaks because of changes in another solution. If instead you only depend on a tested version of some solution, you will be able to adapt to any breaking changes at *your* schedule, instead of that of another team.